# .NET: Is it possible to change the format used by double.ToString()?

Tags: .net, double, globalization, tostring

I have some third party code, that invokes `double.ToString()`. My problem, is that the default `double.ToString()` implementation replaces the decimal dot with a comma, like so:

```
49.99.ToString() == "49,99"
```

This happens, because the default `double.ToString()` uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` whereas I need it to be `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Indeed, observe:

```
49.99.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == "49.99"
49.99.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) == "49,99"
```

Is there a way to change the current culture to be the invariant one, so that `double.ToString()` work as I need it to?

I would like to avoid as much as possible tinkering with the third party code, so please, do not suggest me just using the `ToString(IFormatProvider)` overload instead of the default `ToString()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the culture info of the current thread which is what is used by default:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

and if this is a web application you could set the `culture` and `uiCulture` attributes of the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element in your `web.config`.

Comment: So simple and so true. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mark, glad I could help. Is there something else you would like to ask about or maybe you could consider closing this question?

Comment: 2 minutes delay, 2 minutes delay.

Comment: If I remember correcty, you will need to do this for every thread you instantiate, and for ThreadPool threads also. I would not say this is  common nor recommended. So, it is the only thing you can do with poorly written third party code, unless it does async stuff.

Comment: This is fine for my scenario. But thanks for the warning. (edit) Nope, no async stuff.